# Escribir en la misma línea dentro de un loop

Tags: python, spyder

Tengo un diccionario como el siguiente:

```
a={'Key1': [a,b,c], 'Key2': [c,d,e] , 'Key3': [f,g,h]}
```

Necesito escribirlo en un txt de la siguinte manera:

```
Key1 a b c
Key2 c d e
Key3 f g h
```

Es decir, sin comas.

Comment: Y que has intentado ?? Muéstranos para poder guiarte

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con "Escribir en la misma línea dentro de un loop"?

Comment: ¿ a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h son caracteres o variables?

Answer (score 1):

Los valores hay que encerrarlos entre comillas:

```
a = {'Key1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'Key2': ['c', 'd', 'e'], 'Key3': ['f', 'g', 'h']}
```

y la solución en-un-línea es

```
[print(k, *v) for (k, v) in a.items()]
```

o desglosado, para mejor comprensión:

```
for (k, v) in a.items():
    print(k, *v)
```

produce

```
Key1 a b c
Key2 c d e
Key3 f g h
```

**El operador "*"**

El operador "*" delante de una lista la desempaqueta en una serie de argumentos posicionales. Por ejemplo, en

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

"a" es una lista, y se imprime como tal:

```
>>>print(a)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Pero al anteponer el operador "*", Pyhton primero expande la lista, por lo que `print(*a)` es como si escribieras:

```
>>>print(1, 2, 3)
1 2 3
```

y como son valores sueltos, los imprime con solo un espacio de separación, sin comas.

Comment: Es mejor esperar a ver que ha intentado el OP.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = {'Key1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'Key2': ['c', 'd', 'e'], 'Key3': ['f', 'g', 'h']}
file = open("archivo_de_prueba.txt", "w")
i=1
for k in a:
   string=k+" "+a[k][0]+" "+a[k][1]+" "+a[k][2]+'\n' if i!=len(a) else k+" "+a[k][0]+" "+a[k][1]+" "+a[k][2]
   file.write(string)
   i+=1
file.close()
```

Comment: Es mejor esperar a ver que ha intentado el OP.